# How to only load main model on Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have two model: main model and linked model, be default when page's loaded, forge view will load a both that increase time load page, question is how to only load main model, i'm implemenning with reactjs.
1.
Appreciate any comments.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoDXS.png)

I try using loadDocumentNode method but dont know how to get main model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if you have multiple 'views' inside the drawing?

The 3D Model containing Main and Linked, is a single 'URN'.
Inside the URN, there can be many Revit 'Views'.
You can create Views of the Main, the Linked, a combination of the two, sectioned, individual floors, etc.

Then, inside Forge Viewer (now Viewer SDK), you can pick one of these views.  Pick a view that has a small amount of stuff in it, and it will load quickly.

Here's the code for choosing a 'Revit View'...

##### Example #1

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/

```
var viewables = viewerDocument.getRoot().search({'type':'geometry'});
viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, viewables[0]);
```

---

##### Example #2

or from the 'Simple Viewer' Tutorial, here:
https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/viewer#viewer-logic

```
function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
            resolve(viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry()));
        }
```

on the Revit side, you can create views here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNivtnCIIbs

and this blog post: https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000040960740/en

Does that help ?

Comment: it's work like charm, tks u